# jsGrid with images in SharePoint Control?

Tags: image

How to add image in **SharePoint CONTROL!** jsgrid cell?

```
public static GridField formatGridField(GridField gf, DataColumn dc)
    {
        gf.FieldKey = dc.ColumnName;
        gf.SerializeDataValue = true;

        ...
    }
```